# QTCreator capturing all keyboard shortcuts

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

I can't make a curly bracket, a pipe, a square bracket, ... It opens menus instead.

Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Environments Tab -> Keyboard -> searched for Alt+N/W/F and there is no shortcut assigned to these combinations. Why is it then capturing these shortcuts? Is it possible to disable them completely?

Comment: Obviously it depends on your keyboard layout, but surely those characters are created by "Shift + ..." combinations?

Comment: I restarted the computer and it reset to defaults.

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine by any chance? This happens to me at times when the VM fails to receive the [Alt] or [Ctrl] key release and thinks that button is still pressed.